# Using Google Identity-Aware Proxy and Google SignIn in iOS project

Tags: ios, google-signin, google-iap

We are using Google IAP in our existing iOS application. So on app initialisation we do the authentication for IAP. This works fine. Now, when user clicks on Sign in with google functionality, we have to again show the prompt option where he will register/login to our app. So basically there are 2 client iD's but google SDK doesn't allow signing in again with different client ID. Any help would be appreciated